# How to validate playstore subscription from server side in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to validate PlayStore subscription from server side with rails.
I have tried "candy_check" gem but in that I always got below response.

```
Server message: (Signet::AuthorizationError)
{
 "error" : "invalid_grant",
 "error_description" : "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```

How can I do that can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to verify subscription then try this
https://gist.github.com/jkotchoff/5632813

It is using this gem provided by google.Use this gem for more APIs
https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client